# My QT doesn't have desktop qt 5.15.2 MinGW 64-bit

Tags: c++, qt, driver

I have project Someone created for me, I have Source of that project, I installed the `Qt 4.15.0` and I want to build the existing project, but I don't have `desktop qt 5.15.2 MinGW 64-bit`, the developer created that project used `desktop qt 5.15.2 MinGW 64-bit` but I dont have It in my Kit
[image: Image Of Kit]

Comment: What is your specific question? Have you installed Qt 4.15.2? 4.15.0 is fairly old.

Comment: You probably have to go to the maintenance tool to install the toolset. Go to `Add or remove programs` and look for Qt Maintenance.

Comment: Before trying to install other versions, it might save some time to check whether the features you need from 5.15.2 might already exist in 5.12.11.